# CPU Architecture dependent?

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation, cpu, cpu-architecture

I would like to determine if the below code would allow the CPU to fetch the unsafe_variable twice? Let's assume the compiler will not reorder or optimise the code because of the volatile and _ReadWriteBarrier (on VS). Mutex cannot be used here and I only care about the case of the potential double fetch.

I am not an expert in term of CPU design but what I am concerned about regarding a potential double fetch would be: Speculative execution (Performance optimization technique including branch prediction and prefetch techniques), Register and memory location renaming and the use of reorder buffer and store buffers within one or two CPUs? Please let me know if a double fetch here would be at all possible.

```
int function(void* Data) {
    size_t _varSize = ((volatile DATA *)Data)->unsafe_variable;
    // unsafe_variable is in some kind of shared memory and can change at any time
    _ReadWriteBarrier();
    // this does not prevent against CPU optimisations (MemoryBarrier would)
    if (_varSize > x * y) { return FALSE;}
    size_t size = _varSize - t * q;
    function_xy(size);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing in the C language specifies memory system behavior at this level nor anything about threads, so there is no certain answer.

To be certain you would need exact details of the CPU, OS, and compiler.

However, I doubt any modern architecture would fetch twice from memory to serve any of the purposes you mention, provided computation is not interrputed. Any reference after the first would be to cache.

However, if there is a context switch after the `unsafe_variable` fetch is begun but before `_varSize` can be used, it's imaginable that the fetch might be restarted when this thread continues.

Comment: The [C standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) mentions plenty about threads.

Comment: You raise a good point regarding the case of a context switch. Would it be possible to have a hardware context switch just after the IF?

Comment: I believe the registers would be saved though.

Comment: To reader Lundin: The C Language Standard does not contain the word thread. You may be thinking about the Posix standard, which contains a C API for threads, but is not part of the C Standard.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Comment: I agree that if the value made it all the way to a register a fetch would not be restarted.  I'm hypthesizing that the memory system might be only part way through the fetch when the interrupt occurs and this intermediate state might be dumped. I know for a fact that e.g string instructions are subject to restart in some architectures, which means fetches can occur more than once.  This doesn't seem likely when loading a single word as you say. But it's imaginable.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing volatile memory location counts as a side-effect in the C standard C11 5.1.2.3/2:

> "Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
>   that does any of those operations are all side effects"

and the compiler is not allowed to generate code that causes additional side-effects. It is explicitly not allowed to generate code that causes additional access of volatile variables (C11 5.1.2.3/6).

But then you are using VC++ so all bets are off. It barely follows any standard. I would advise to use a strictly conforming C compiler instead, if possible.

Comment: VC++ seems to work with volatile as it would with _ReadWriteBarrier(), it would block compiler optimization/reordering. I am more concerned about CPU optimizations that could allow a double fetch here.

Comment: @Bookix The compiler is not allowed to generate code that performs more than one access of `Data`, since that would violate the C standard. A compiler is written/ported for a specific CPU and the compiler is therefore the one responsible for ensuring that instruction caching in multiple cores does not break the expected behavior of the code.

Comment: This seems not to answer this question. The question is not about compiler, but about CPU speculative reads and similar features.

Comment: @Read the comment 1 line up. A compiler can't be allowed to be oblivious about the system it targets.